# delete a project from console.moovweb.com

Tags: moovweb

I have created a couple of projects in my moovweb account in the cloud.  I want to delete those projects. When I go to the control center I am not able to locate a delete button in the project list.  Need the information will I be able to delete a project from my account and if possible how? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can delete any Project (now known as Sites in version 5.0) in **Settings** > **Site Admin**

For version 4.7:

1. from the main Project listing page, click the name of the Project you wish to delete
2. from the Project page, click the Settings button in upper right
3. click Site Admin in sidebar navigation
4. at the bottom, click Delete button

For version 5.0 Preview:

1. from the main Site listing page, click the name of the project you wish to delete
2. from the Site page, click the Site Settings button in upper right
3. click the Site Admin tab
4. at the bottom, click Delete button